# How to call a function in useEffect() outside of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to call a function in `useEffect()` by doing this:

```js
const myComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const aFunc = () => {
      console.log("function called")
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <button onClick={() => aFunc()} />
  )
}
```

As you can see, everytime I click on the `<button>` I would like to call the `aFunc()` function.

How can I call the `aFunc` outside of `useEffect()` but in the same component? It seems that React can't recognize the function when I bind it in the `onClick`

Comment: Don't declare `aFunc` in `useEffect()`, instead, remove the `useEffect()` (since `const` is block-scoped you'll only be able to use `aFunc` within the `useEffect()` callback with your current setup)

Comment: You must defined `aFunc` in the scope of your component if you want to use it this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The function exists in a different scope.

The point of `useEffect` is to isolate code so it doesn't rerun every time a component renders. The most common use for this is to make an Ajax request for data when the component is added to the document *without* triggering an infinite loop as every Ajax response causes the component to rerender and trigger the Ajax request to be made again.

Just declare the function directly inside the component or, since the function in this particular example doesn't depend on any data from the component, entirely outside the component.

---

If your example is massively over simplified and the process of creating the function is expensive and dependent on data in the component: Look at `useCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use useEffect for this,

```
const myComponent = () => {
          const aFunc = () => {
              console.log("function called")
          }
        
          return (
            <button onClick={() => aFunc()} />
          )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Dostonbek Oripjonov's answer

Just declare the function outside the useEffect hook and then call it from inside the hook.

This would allow you to use that function in other places too!

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this

```
const myComponent = () => {
  const aFunc = () => {
      console.log("function called")
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    aFunc()
  }, [])

  return (
    <button onClick={() => aFunc()} />
  )
}
```